# TensorFlow does not detect CUDA

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I installed the CUDA toolkit and CUDNN and added it to the PATH, but this function still returns **False**.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())
```

I use JupyterNotebook from the Anaconda distribution.

The OS is Windows 11. CUDA v11. CUDNN v8.7. Also have zlib dll.

The command

`nvcc -V`

in PowerShell works, it outputs the CUDA version.

TensorFlow also does not detect the graphics card because of CUDA.

```
print(tensorflow.config.list_physical_devices())
```

This code returns information only about CPU.

Comment: This means you have a CPU only build of Tensorflow installed

Comment: @talonmies I thought tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu are the same package since TensorFlow 2.1. How can i check what tensorflow i have?

Comment: `is_built_with_cuda` returning false is self evidently a CPU only build

Comment: @talonmies How can i configure it to work with gpu? Sorry for stupid questions i just started learning it

Comment: You can’t. You must find a GPU build and install that instead. GPU support is compiled in, you cannot  add it by configuration afterwards

Comment: Please follow the step by step instructions mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#software_requirements) to configure the GPU setup in conda environment after fulfilling all the software requirements. Let us know with the OS, python and tensorflow version details if the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `CUDA 11.2` and `cuDNN 8.1` as per this [build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) to enable Tensorflow GPU support in your system.

Please install all the required [software](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#software_requirements) for GPU support and set the [PATH](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#set_your_path) for these software to the bin directory.

Then use below code for **TF-gpu** setup in conda environment.

```
conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1.0
pip install --upgrade pip
# Anything above 2.10 is not supported on the GPU on Windows Native
pip install "tensorflow-gpu<2.11"
```

To verify the GPU setup:

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```